# How can Wagtail CMS pages be edited directly as HTML, instead of as the default WYSIWYG block editor?

Tags: html, cms, django

I work on a website that uses Wagtail CMS, a Django web framework. Its page editor uses blocks (https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.9/topics/pages.html) and I don't see any simple options or instructions for entering page content as HTML, as is possible for WordPress (i.e. https://wordpress.org/support/article/writing-code-in-your-posts/).

How can HTML content be filled in for pages of a Wagtail CMS-based website? I'm generating page content programmatically for a project, and the page output I've prepared is in HTML. If this was a WordPress site I'd enter the contents in the post HTML editor. Does Wagtail have any kind of HTML editor?

Answer (score 2):

Not a Django user but I guess you will have to install a different WYSIWYG Editor from the Package list

https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/wysiwyg/

Some of them have the HTML content editable feature you are looking for.